# onChange is not working in react functional component while changing the value through state update

Tags: reactjs, input, react-functional-component

I am using mapbox in a project and here I am trying to get the latitude and longitude from the input box. I have set a value in input field and I want to change it while writing the   but nothing is changing in the input box while trying to write something.

Please check the code

```
 const [marker, setMarker] = useState({
    latitude: 20.2961,
    longitude: 85.8245
  });
```

This is the rended input.

```
           <div className='flex gap-6'>
                <div className='relative w-1/2'>
                  <input onChange={(e) => setMarker({latitude:e.target.value, ...marker})}  value={marker.latitude} type="number" placeholder='Latitude' className='py-4 w-full pl-12 text-xs rounded-md focus:outline-none border border-bottom-border' name="" id="" />
                  <MapPin className='absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-2 bg-[#0000000d] p-2 rounded text-gray-500' size={30} weight="bold" />
                </div>
                <div className='relative w-1/2'>
                  <input onChange={(e) => setMarker({longitude:e.target.value, ...marker})} value={marker.longitude} type="number" placeholder='Longitude' className='py-4 w-full pl-12 text-xs rounded-md focus:outline-none border border-bottom-border' name="" id="" />
                  <MapPin className='absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-2 bg-[#0000000d] p-2 rounded text-gray-500' size={30} weight="bold" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Please help if you know the solution.

Comment: without spread operator:
setMarker({ longitude:e.target.value, latitude: marker.latitude })}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator should be used first here. Use something like this

```
onChange={(e) => setMarker({...marker, latitude:e.target.value })}
```

Comment: it's a great idea